# Nagios and Twilio

Tags: twilio, nagios

I want to configure SMS and call alerts with Twilio for Nagios but I can't find the way.

I already have Twilio account but I have doubts on how to define the necessary scripts and modifications in Nagios.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you explain what you tried so far to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @Carl, here are results from Google: https://nagiosenterprises.my.site.com/support/s/article/Twilio-SMS-Integration-b541fa4f

chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Twilio_SMS_Integration_With_XI.pdf

Hope you find them useful!